# How can I store nested Hashmap in Redis?

Tags: java, redis, hashmap

I want to store netsted `HashMap` in `Redis` having single key.

For example :

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> map = new  HashMap<>();
```

Please Suggest :

- Is there any way to store the above-mentioned data structure?
- How can we achieve this?

Comment: If you have the same key and multiple key-value, you also can use HashOperations of RedisTemplate like: 

redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(key, hashKey, value);

Check this for more details: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/core/HashOperations.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis doesn't support it as of now. However there is a way to do it, other than `rejson`.

You can convert it into JSON and store in Redis and retrieve. Following utility methods, which I use in Jackson.

**To convert Object to String :**

```
public static String stringify(Object object) {
    ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
    jackson.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    try {
        return jackson.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while creating json: ", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example : `stringify(obj);`

**To convert String to Object :**

```
public static <T> T objectify(String content, TypeReference valueType) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
        mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return mapper.readValue(content, valueType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "returning null because of error : {0}", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example : `List<Object> list = objectify("Your Json", new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){})`

You can update this method as per your requirement. I am sure, you know, how to add and update in Redis.

Answer (score 4):

REDIS now allows nested HashMap https://redis.io/topics/data-types

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public class Redis {

    @Autowired
    RedisService redisService;

    @Cacheable(value = "name", key = "keyvalue")
    public Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> redisNestedMap(String keyvalue) {
        return redisService.getNestedMap();
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class RedisService {

    public Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> getNestedMap() {
        Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<>();
        value.put("key", "value");
        nestedMap.put("one", value);
        return nestedMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: Redis does not support nested HashMap. Its the library that is doing all the magic I perassume.

Answer (score 3):

Redis doesn't support storing hash inside hash. But there is [REDIS as a JSON store](https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/) that can store JSON in REDIS, It allows storing, updating and fetching JSON values from Redis keys. I think this can help you to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

According to my recent research Redis does'nt support nested hasmap.
So on my own solution I used ObjectMapper to convert nestedHasmap as Json string for storing in Redis.